# C# Finding a specific string's memory address of another process

Tags: c#, memory, process, memory-address

I need to get memory address of a string with C#; so I can read/write with ReadProcessMemory and WriteProcessMemory.

Like part 1 of this link, but it teaches how to find it with OllyDbg, I need to do that with C#.
http://www.codingvision.net/security/c-read-write-another-process-memory

**Edit**

Every time I run that process with OllyDbg it gives me a different address I'm looking for a unit address of a variable, which allow me to read/write that with C#.

Comment: Even if you could do this, the string could get moved around during GC at any point. But that's a moot point because I can see no way you can do this.

Comment: call ollydbg as an external process an have it return the information to c# caller. [run extern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11454934/862973)

Comment: I'm using ollydbg just for getting info

Answer (score 0):

Recreating what OllyDbg does would be extremely hard, what you could do is find the static address of the value you are looking for using for example OllyDbg or CheatEngine pointer scan.
You can then use that address and pointer in your c# program to read and write to it.

The adress you are trying to use is changing because you aren't using a static address but one that is replaced on every restart of the program.

You can find lots of tutorials on how to find static addresses/pointers on YouTube.